# In-place operation Error for Simple Addition and Subtraction Operations

Tags: python, pytorch, autograd

When I run the following code with one layer network it works well. However, when I switch to two layer network it generates the Following Error. Can Some help me resolve the issue. The code is cloned from the following GitHub Repo.
https://github.com/amina01/ESMIL

> RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has
> been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.cuda.FloatTensor [230,
> 1]], which is output 0 of TBackward, is at version 2; expected version
> 1 instead. Hint: enable anomaly detection to find the operation that
> failed to compute its gradient, with
> torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True).

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch

import numpy as np
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score as auc_roc
from sklearn import metrics
import scipy.io
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, bags):
        self.bags = bags

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        examples = self.bags[index]
        return examples
        
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.bags)
            

'''
Single Layer Architecture
'''


#class Net(nn.Module):
#    def __init__(self,d):
#        super(Net, self).__init__()
#        self.out = nn.Linear(d,1)        


#    def forward(self,x):
#        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
#        x = self.out(x)
#        return x
'''
One Hidden Layer Architecture
'''

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,d):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.hidden1 = nn.Linear(d,d)        
        self.out = nn.Linear(d,1)

    def forward(self,x):
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.hidden1(x)
        x = F.tanh(x)
        
        x = self.out(x)
        return x



def create_bags_mat(path='data\\elephant_100x100_matlab.mat'):
    mat=scipy.io.loadmat(path)
    ids=mat['bag_ids'][0]
    f=scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.todense(mat['features'])
    l=np.array(scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.todense(mat['labels']))[0]
    bags=[]
    labels=[]
    for i in set(ids):
        bags.append(np.array(f[ids==i]))
        labels.append(l[ids==i][0])
    bags=np.array(bags)
    labels=np.array(labels)
    return bags, labels
    
    

    
aucs=[]
accs=[]
bags, labels=create_bags_mat()


skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10)
for train, test in skf.split(bags, labels):

    bags_tr=bags[train]
    y_tr=labels[train]
    bags_ts=bags[test]
    y_ts=labels[test]
    pos_bags=bags_tr[y_tr>0]
    neg_bags=bags_tr[y_tr<0]


    
    pos=MyDataset(pos_bags)
    neg=MyDataset(neg_bags)
    
    loader_pos = DataLoader(pos, batch_size=1)
    loader_neg = DataLoader(neg, batch_size=1)
    epochs=10
    mlp=Net(230)
    mlp.cuda()
#    torch.set_default_tensor_type('torch.cuda.FloatTensor')
    optimizer = optim.Adam(mlp.parameters())
    
    all_losses=[]
    for e in range(epochs):
        l=0.0
        for idx_p, pbag in enumerate(loader_pos):
            pbag=pbag.float()
            pbag=Variable(pbag).type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor)
            p_scores=mlp.forward(pbag[0])
            max_p=torch.max(p_scores)
    
            for idx_n, nbag in enumerate(loader_neg):
                nbag=nbag.float()
                nbag=Variable(nbag).type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor)
                n_scores=mlp.forward(nbag[0])

                max_n=torch.max(n_scores)
                z=np.array([0.0])
                loss=torch.max(Variable(torch.from_numpy(z)).type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor), (max_n-max_p+1))
#                loss=torch.max(torch.tensor(0.0), (max_n-max_p+1))
                l=l+float(loss)
    
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                loss.backward(retain_graph=True)

                optimizer.step()
        all_losses.append(l)
    #testing

    test=MyDataset(bags_ts)
    loader_ts=DataLoader(test, batch_size=1)
    predictions=[]

    for param in mlp.parameters():
        param.requires_grad =False
    for idx_ts, tsbag in enumerate(loader_ts):
        tsbag=tsbag.float()
        tsbag=Variable(tsbag).type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor)
        scores=mlp.forward(tsbag[0])

        predictions.append(float(torch.max(scores)))
    auc=auc_roc(y_ts, predictions)
    aucs.append(auc)
    print ('AUC=',auc)
    
    
    f, t, a=metrics.roc_curve(y_ts, predictions)
    AN=sum(x<0 for x in y_ts)
    AP=sum(x>0 for x in y_ts)
    TN=(1.0-f)*AN
    TP=t*AP
    Acc2=(TP+TN)/len(y_ts)
    acc=max(Acc2)
    print ('accuracy=',acc )
    accs.append(acc)
    
print ("\n\nmean auc=", np.mean(aucs))
print ("mean acc=", np.mean(accs))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error was arising due to the max_p=torch.max(p_scores) operation in backpropagation. The problem is be resolved by adding with torch.no_grad():  max_p=torch.max(p_scores) under the first loop. Now the overall code looks like this: However, The performance of the model degraded.

> ```
>         pbag=pbag.float()
>         pbag=Variable(pbag).type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor)
>         p_scores=mlp.forward(pbag[0])
>         with torch.no_grad():
>             max_p=torch.max(p_scores)
> ```